# Passing a gaussian through a non-linear function gives another gaussian. How?

Tags: linear-algebra, normal-distribution

I have a doubt. I understand that Gaussians do not result in another Gaussian when it is composed with a non-linear function.

But why does this not hold true for $f(x) = 2x+1$ (which is a non-linear function as $f(0) \neq 0$)

The output is another scaled Gaussian with a shifted mean.

Comment: Affine transformations are still isometries despite being non-linear.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean function composition rather than function multiplication (as the product is certainly not a Gaussian function), the answer can be understood geometrically.
Composing the Gaussian function $g$ with the function $f(x)=2x+1$ translates $g$ left by 1 unit, then dilates it by a factor of $1/2$ in the $x$-axis.
Both of these transformations preserve the characteristic 'bell-shape' of the Gaussian functions. The main difference being that the mean has decreased by $1$ and the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g\circ f (x) dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) dx.$$
In essence, we do not require $f(0)=0$ for $g\circ f$ to be Gaussian. However, for the other order of composition $f\circ g$ is Gaussian for $f$ linear and $g$ Gaussian iff $f(x)=ax$ for some $a\neq 0$.